# skip missing values in a for loop

Tags: idl-programming-language, msg

I have a folder with 1000 tifs. I'd like to read 4 tifs, do some calculation and read the next 4 tifs. The problem is, that for example tif number 500 is missing. Now my current program stops right bevor tif number 500.

So my idea is that I check if the **path** exists with file_test and /directory and skip all missing values in the foor loop.

Directory: Set this keyword to return 1 (true) if File exists and is a directory. true =1, false = 0

```
for j = 0, 1102 do begin

PathEx = File_test(e:\Meteosat\Tiff\2016\06\17\MSG_201606170100_B4_L.tif', directory)

if PathEx = 1 then
B = READ_TIFF(e:\Meteosat\Tiff\2016\06\17\MSG_201606170100_B4_L.tif, GEOTIFF=tags)

if PathEx = 0 then
print, 'missing' and continue
```

end

I want to skip all missing paths. I don't know how to do this. I Also read something about
    .CONTINUE

But I have no clue how this works too.
thank you!
pampi

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are using the correct syntax.  Your code should be something like the following:

```
FOR j=0L, 1102L DO BEGIN
  PathEx = FILE_TEST('e:\Meteosat\Tiff\2016\06\17\MSG_201606170100_B4_L.tif', /DIRECTORY)
  IF (PathEx[0] EQ 0) THEN CONTINUE    ;;  This will jump to the next index
  b = READ_TIFF('e:\Meteosat\Tiff\2016\06\17\MSG_201606170100_B4_L.tif',GEOTIFF=tags)
ENDFOR
```

You should probably have a list of file names and then index those.  Suppose you call them something like `filenames` and this is a [N]-element string array.  Then you would do something like the following within the above loop:

```
file = filenames[j]
PathEx = FILE_TEST(file[0],/DIRECTORY)
IF (PathEx[0] EQ 0) THEN CONTINUE    ;;  This will jump to the next index
b = READ_TIFF(file[0],GEOTIFF=tags)
```

I should also mention that the variable `b` should either be an array or you should have an array defined outside the loop that you can store data into, otherwise all your operations within the `FOR` loop will be lost.

Comment: I will try it! I did it with

    if (PathEx eq 0) then continue
    if (PathEx eq 0) then begin

But this doesn't worked very well!

Thanks!